# Revmob Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: revmob

I am using OSX 10.7.5, XCode 4.5, RevMob v 5.5.1.

When I am clicking the play button on the top left hand corner, XCode generated these error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[BCFAdsReachability connectionRequired] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
      -[BCFAdsReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
```

Screenshots: 
[image]

Here is the compile source and link library list, in case someone refer me to some old threads:

[image]

I guess I have already linked all the binary correctly.  However, I did use simulator and my iPhone to try the app but it still shows the above error.

Can you please tell me what is missing and what should be done to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add the **SystemConfiguration** framework as required in their [docs](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios#configuration).